# Multiple jQueries causing issues to load other jQuery plugins

Tags: jquery

My page has multiple jQuery plugins, addging more causes plugins to break

These are the scripts am using

```
<script src="scripts/jquery.js"></script>
<script src="scripts/jquery.nav.js"></script>
<script src="scripts/jquery-1.7.2.min.js"></script>
<!--If I remove this ^ script things work but this is required by other plugin-->
<script src="scripts/jquery-ui-1.8.21.custom.min.js"></script>
<script src="scripts/jquery.mousewheel.min.js"></script>
<script src="scripts/jquery.mCustomScrollbar.js"></script>
<script src="scripts/jquery.scrollTo.js"></script>
```

I also tried using jQuery `noconflict` but no luck

Comment: What version of jQuery is the jquery.js file? If it's before 1.7.2, then you can likely get rid of it and just keep the later one. If it's after 1.7.2, it probably also has whatever the plugins that require 1.7.2 require in it anyway.

Comment: @AnthonyGrist `v@1.8.0` but If I remove that than one or the other plugin is not working

Comment: What plugin is *not* working?  That would be useful information.

Comment: @FelixBonkoski m using 4 plugins, page scroll, rotator, custom scroll, and a slider, if I remove 1.7.2 everything works except the custom scroll, If I keep 1.7.2 than custom scroll works fine but everything else is spoiled

Comment: Shrug. Obviously, as others said you should only be loading one jquery. As I recall, 1.8.0 had a bunch of bugs, so you should at least try loading 1.8.3, upgrade all your plugins to their latest versions, and see what happens.  Otherwise, we'd have to see some code, or a jsFiddle to see which plugin is failing.  Also, may be worth noting that jquery.nav.js requires scrollTo plugin (cf: https://github.com/davist11/jQuery-One-Page-Nav) so you should include jquery.scrollTo.js *before* jquery.nav.js

Answer (score 0):

This is just duplicated reference to jQuery. if your first line is referencing jquery 1.8.0 as you mentioned, then you do not need jquery-1.7.2.min.js.

If you still having issues, first make sure that you are referencing jquery 1.8.0 (you can download the latest or just hot-link to jquery hosted files). If you still have an issue, you need to show some code snippets along with what the error is. It could be irrelevant.